# Como transformar Y-m-d para Unix timestamp à meia noite em PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Boa tarde,

Estou precisando converter os dados de um formulário que vem no formato ex: 2018-02-13 para UNIX à meia-noite.
Se eu converto normalmente usando o strtotime ele vem certo mas com o horário as 6:00AM.

Alguem pode dar uma luz?
Obrigado =)

Comment: $unixMeiaNoite = strtotime($dataFormulario." 00:00:00");

Comment: Esse meia-noite é confuso. Meia-noite do dia `2018-02-13` é o próximo segundo  depois de `2018-02-13 23:59:59`, ou seja `2018-02-14 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, 
$check_in = strtotime('-6 hour' , strtotime($arrival));